# Buildout and django-registration from repository for Django 1.5

Tags: django, django-registration, buildout, django-1.5

I'd like to use Buildout to get django-registration with Django 1.5, and I have a custom user using MyUser(AbstractUser). I used to get it from the recipe v0.8 and it was great. Since, I switched to 1.5, remove my UserProfile and use this custom MyUser.

django-registration no longer work. I've been told I should get it from the repository, and that's what I'm trying to do. I've in the past used mr.developer to get a newer version of django-tastypie, and I tried to reproduce the same with django-registration. I have an error while calling bin/buildout tho. Let's first check the buildout config:

```
[buildout]
extensions = mr.developer
parts = myquivers
eggs =
    django-registration
include-site-packages = false
versions = versions
sources = sources
auto-checkout =
    django-registration

[sources]
django-registration = hg https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration

[versions]
django = 1.5

[myquivers]
recipe = djangorecipe
settings = development
eggs = ${buildout:eggs}
project = myquivers
```

Pretty simple config. It used to work with tastypie like I said, and I'm trying to do the same steps:
- python2.7 bootstrap.py
- bin/buildout
- bin/develop activate django-registration
- bin/develop checkout django-registration
- bin/myquivers syncdb
- bin/myquivers runservser

But it fails at the bin/buildout steps:

```
$ bin/buildout 
Getting distribution for 'mr.developer'.
Got mr.developer 1.25.
mr.developer: Creating missing sources dir /home/damien/Documents/projects/myquivers/src.
mr.developer: Queued 'django-registration' for checkout.
mr.developer: Cloned 'django-registration' with mercurial.
Develop: '/home/damien/Documents/projects/myquivers/src/django-registration'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/tmpzLDggG", line 13, in <module>
    exec(compile(open('/home/damien/Documents/projects/myquivers/src/django-registration/setup.py').read(), '/home/damien/Documents/projects/myquivers/src/django-registration/setup.py', 'exec'))
  File "/home/damien/Documents/projects/myquivers/src/django-registration/setup.py", line 30, in <module>
    version=get_version().replace(' ', '-'),
  File "/home/damien/Documents/projects/myquivers/src/django-registration/registration/__init__.py", line 5, in get_version
    from django.utils.version import get_version as django_get_version
ImportError: No module named django.utils.version
While:
  Installing.
  Processing develop directory '/home/damien/Documents/projects/myquivers/src/django-registration'.

An internal error occured due to a bug in either zc.buildout or in a
recipe being used:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/damien/Documents/projects/myquivers/eggs/zc.buildout-2.1.0-py2.7.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1923, in main
    getattr(buildout, command)(args)
  File "/home/damien/Documents/projects/myquivers/eggs/zc.buildout-2.1.0-py2.7.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 466, in install
    installed_develop_eggs = self._develop()
  File "/home/damien/Documents/projects/myquivers/eggs/zc.buildout-2.1.0-py2.7.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 707, in _develop
    zc.buildout.easy_install.develop(setup, dest)
  File "/home/damien/Documents/projects/myquivers/eggs/zc.buildout-2.1.0-py2.7.egg/zc/buildout/easy_install.py", line 871, in develop
    call_subprocess(args)
  File "/home/damien/Documents/projects/myquivers/eggs/zc.buildout-2.1.0-py2.7.egg/zc/buildout/easy_install.py", line 129, in call_subprocess
    % repr(args)[1:-1])
Exception: Failed to run command:
'/usr/bin/python2.7', '/tmp/tmpzLDggG', '-q', 'develop', '-mxN', '-d', '/home/damien/Documents/projects/myquivers/develop-eggs/tmpYM_dR9build'
```

Checking at the error, first Django seems not to be in the system, and that's right, when entering python2.7 and try >>> import django, it fails. But that's normal and that's why I'm using buildout, to not install system-wide Django, just locally for my project.

Any idea how to fix this? Is there a better alternative than taking this repo version? Please let me know, again, custom user/django 1.5/django-registration.

Thanks!

Comment: There is a bug in the latest version of django-registration, that's why. This file https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/src/b3c41b3c7f50523b4ecb8267d6d27a918adc2e1f/registration/__init__.py?at=default is the issue, so I'm using a previous version for now.

Comment: The patch related to this issue: https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/pull-request/41/removed-dependency-on-django-during/diff